# webClient POST does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I'm trying to POST a form to a server using webClient. Here's my code for the request.

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

NameValueCollection myNameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();

myNameValueCollection.Add("about", about);
myNameValueCollection.Add("firstname", firstname);
myNameValueCollection.Add("lastname", lastname);
Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.102:1992/api/member/updateprofile");
myWebClient.UploadValuesAsync(uri,"POST", myNameValueCollection);
```

This request doesn't make it to the server. I have checked the Url and it's correct as I can make request with fiddler and using httpWebRequest client. I don't see anything wrong with my code. What could be the issue here?

My server side code looks as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("updateprofile")]
public HttpResponseMessage updateProfile()
{
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ok, you are showing the attribute route on the action. but there is not details about the controller's route/route prefix that matches the url you displayed. confirm the routes and that you are configuring them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are showing the attribute route on the action. but there is not details about the controller's route/route prefix that matches the url you displayed.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/member")]
public class MemberController : ApiController {

    //eg POST api/member/updateprofile
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("updateprofile")]
    public HttpResponseMessage updateProfile() {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        return result;
    }
}
```

confirm your routes and that you are configuring them properly.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The route is configured properly. RoutePrefix looks like this :[RoutePrefix("api/member")]. There's nothing wrong with the Url. I've checked it with Fiddlerand it works fine.

Comment: keep fiddler running and look at what it sees when you execute your code. inspect the raw request and compare it to the ones that worked. That should give you an idea of what may be causing your problem